# how to use navigation and stage together

Tags: ros, navigation, simulator-stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

### My program use navigation and stage both stack. but when i try to install navigation stack i got the following Message to uninstall my stage

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-navigation
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-43 linux-headers-3.2.0-43-generic linux-headers-3.5.0-23
  libjpeg62 linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libhdf5-serial-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev
  libsdl-image1.2-dev libtiff4-dev libvtk5-dev ros-electric-perception-pcl
Suggested packages:
  libhdf5-doc vtk-examples vtk-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libjpeg62-dev ros-electric-stage
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libhdf5-serial-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev
  libsdl-image1.2-dev libtiff4-dev libvtk5-dev ros-electric-navigation
  ros-electric-perception-pcl
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 2 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/117 MB of archives.
After this operation, 445 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64397/how-to-use-navigation-and-stage-together/) by [mohiuddin.kawsar](https://answers.ros.org/users/5063/mohiuddin.kawsar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's likely that libjpeg-dev and libjpeg62-dev are incompatible. I hope this was resolved at some point quite a while ago.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0